# forkJoin returns and observable

Tags: angular, observable

I'm not sure if the title is correct for this question but i have a following scenario.

```
const catalog$ = this.proxy.getCatalogData(); // this is an http req
const pay$ = this.proxy.getPaydData(); // this is an http req
const acc$ = this.proxy.getAccData(); // this is an http req
const service$ = this.proxy.getServiceData(); // this is an http req and returns some error or throwError(503)

let arr = [
  catalog$,
  pay$,
  acc$,
  service$
];

arr = arr.map(item => item.pipe(catchError(err => of(err)));

forkJoin(arr).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data); // [{...}, {...}, {...}, Observable]
});
```

Now even though i have forkJoin i get an observable in the callback data for the api which throwing error.
Is there is way that i can resolve or get the data form the error observable inside the data array? so i dont have to process it any more.

Comment: please share proxy functions

Comment: It's just http.get() methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get it because you are sending one observable from `catchError` from the pipe:

```
arr = arr.map(item => item.pipe(catchError(err => of(err)));
// --------Here-----------------------------------^^^^^^^
```

`of()` returns an observable with the args provided.

You can just return the `error`

```
arr = arr.map(item => item.pipe(catchError(err => err));
```

Now you can get the error object.

Comment: But then it cries for the type of arr. When I do not return of(err) then the array has observables and an object. So ts gives error regarding the type

Comment: What i the error? can you provide that?

Comment: Type 'Observable<PlatformHealthCheckStatusServiceModel | { status: any; results: { '': { status: any; description: any; }; }; }>[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<PlatformHealthCheckStatusServiceModel>[]

The above is error